# Is "Don't just talk to your audience, play with them" correct ?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I am about to print out some business cards and I was wondering if

```
Don't just talk to your audience, play with them
```

is correct. I understand that as "audience" is singular, it should be

```
Don't just talk to your audience, play with it
```

but that just sounds weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, *them* is perfectly fine with *audience*.  Just so you are aware, sometimes *playing with someone* can mean *messing with their mind*- leading them to believe something that isn't true for a joking or playful purpose.  When they eventually catch on and call you on it, the typical reply is, "Nah, I was just playin' with ya."

Comment: How about "Connect with your audience, don't just talk to them"?

Comment: I've got one .. "Don't just talk to your audience, work with them."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I like the "Connect with your Audience". Work with them is a bit limited, my startup is a platform where you can build your own game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Audience" is singular, and while it can mean an audience of one (as in "an audience with the Pope") it is more often used as a collective noun referring to a group of individuals, just as a football team is composed of a group of individuals. In your first example, audience refers to the group, and you've made an understood transition in the second part from the singular of the group, to the plural of the members of the group. Before I read Jim's comment, I had the same reaction to the phrase "play with them". ON a business card, where the opportunity for further context is limited, I would suggest "engage" instead of "play with".